# How to load a text file into a Hive table stored as sequence files

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a hive table stored as a sequencefile.

I need to load a text file into this table.  How do I load the data into this table?

Answer (score 55):

You can load the text file into a textfile Hive table and then insert the data from this table into your sequencefile.

Start with a tab delimited file:

```
% cat /tmp/input.txt
a       b
a2      b2
```

create a sequence file

```
hive> create table test_sq(k string, v string) stored as sequencefile;
```

try to load; as expected, this will fail:

```
hive> load data local inpath '/tmp/input.txt' into table test_sq;
```

But with this table:

```
hive> create table test_t(k string, v string) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile;
```

The load works just fine:

```
hive> load data local inpath '/tmp/input.txt' into table test_t;
OK
hive> select * from test_t;
OK
a       b
a2      b2
```

Now load into the sequence table from the text table:

```
insert into table test_sq select * from test_t;
```

Can also do load/insert with *overwrite* to replace all.

Comment: could that be done directly, can we load to sequence format table stuff from TSV file without intermediate saving to other table?

Comment: No it can't be done. The only easiest way to load data into sequence file is the above way. The same is reaffirmed by apche wiki https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CompressedStorage

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly create a table stored as a sequence file and insert text into it. You must do this:

1. Create a table stored as text
2. Insert the text file into the text table
3. Do a CTAS to create the table stored as a sequence file.
4. Drop the text table if desired

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_txt(field1 int, field2 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/file.tsv' INTO TABLE test_txt;

CREATE TABLE test STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
AS SELECT * FROM test_txt;

DROP TABLE test_txt;
```

Comment: LOAD DATA INPATH syntax is wrong... the INTO is needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to create table as textfile and move the file to the appropriate location

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mytable(col1 string, col2 string) 
row format delimited fields terminated by '|' stored as textfile;

Copy the file to the HDFS Location where table is created.

 Hope this helps!!!