# How to count number of lines of a file hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, wc

I'm trying to count the number of lines in a file in `hdfs`/`HIVE`.  There are some cases where I want the number of lines of the entire table in `HIVE`, and some cases where I want the number of lines just in a file in `HIVE`.

I've tried some things like `!hadoop fs -count /<path to file(s)/`, but this only gives the `FILE COUNT`, then `CONTENT_SIZE`.   from [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.pdf)

How do I get the number of lines?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the total number of lines you could check the 'Map Input Records' counter. This will give you the total number of lines in a given input (this is all the files in the directory).

If you need the number of lines in a given file (I still don't get why you'd need that) you need to get the same counter for the mapper that has read the given file. This can get a bit tricky, but it's doable.

If you're using Hadoop over Yarn I'd advise you to use [Yarn's REST API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html), it's really easy to use and very convenient to do this kind of "fast queries" over some parts of the M/R processing.

Answer (score 1):

Hive won't let you create Tables on top of just a file. 
Remember, when you create a table in Hive you create it on top of a folder. (which allows us to add more files)

There is only way to read only one file into a table in hive.

> load data [local] inpath '/input_folder/input_file.txt' into table dest_table;

To count the number of lines in that table

> select count(*) from dest_table;

Link below has some useful information:

[How to load a text file into a Hive table stored as sequence files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064193/how-to-load-a-text-file-into-a-hive-table-stored-as-sequence-files)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this approach as it requires creating a Hive table just to count lines, which is a pretty big side effect. I'd lean towards using Pig as per the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612867/how-to-count-lines-in-a-file-on-hdfs-command, as this doesn't require any temporary storage to be created, or for the data to be copied anywhere.

Comment: Agreed Ben.. but he wants use only one file and so I suggested that approach.